# Cannot run Julia script from command line in .julia directory

Tags: julia

When I try to run a script in the .julia directory from the command line it fails, example below:

```
D:\MyProjects\Julia\.julia\v0.4\Mocha\tools>julia plot_statistics.jl
ERROR: could not open file d:\myprojects\julia\plot_statistics.jl
 in include at boot.jl:261
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:320
 in process_options at client.jl:280
 in _start at client.jl:378

D:\MyProjects\Julia\.julia\v0.4\Mocha\tools>julia "d:\MyProjects\Julia\.julia\v0.4\Mocha\tools\plot_statistics.jl"
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: ArgParse not found in path
 in require at loading.jl:249
 in include at boot.jl:261
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:320
 in process_options at client.jl:280
 in _start at client.jl:378
while loading d:\MyProjects\Julia\.julia\v0.4\Mocha\tools\plot_statistics.jl, in expression starting on line 2
```

Notice in the first attempt the error message is missing a significant portion of the path, everything from .julia on.

In the second attempt I try to give the full path, but Julia rejects that too.

*Windows 10; Julia is on the path (e.g. `julia` enters the REPL); Julia ver. 0.4.5*

Comment: The answer to the second one is just to install the ArgParse package: `Pkg.add("ArgParse")`, I'll leave this open if anyone wants to venture an answer as to why the first attempt failed.

Comment: Do you have anything in your .juliarc.jl file?

Comment: I have added the directory for `plot_statistics.jl` to my `.juliarc` file. From the REPL I can `import plot_statitics.jl` successfully. But from the command line I cannot run `julia plot_statistics.jl`, I get `ERROR: could not open file d:\myprojects\julia\plot_statistics.jl`, it seems like julia command line is not using LOAD_PATH from  `.juliarc`

Comment: I notice that the path I listed is my HOME environment path rather than looking at LOAD_PATH to find the file. Perhaps I don't understand what LOAD_PATH is meant for?